# Ejecutar comandos oracle desde ssh.net

Tags: c#, oracle, .net-core, ssh

Buen dia a todos, estoy haciendo un código en C# .net-core para conectarme por medio de ssh a un servidor linux
para automatizar una tarea

de inicio ejecuto algunos comandos para ver dentro de carpetas e imprimir el resultado como por ejemplo

```
sc = sshclient.CreateCommand("ls /carp_resp/resp_semanal");
sc.Execute();
answer = sc.Result;
Console.WriteLine(answer);
```

Resultado

**oracle_186634522987.log**

todo bien hasta aquí, pero al querer pasar como parámetro los siguientes comandos que sirven para conectarme a la Bb Oracle y hacer consultas

```
    sc = sshclient.CreateCommand("sqlplus /nolog");
    sc.Execute();
    answer = sc.Result;
    Console.WriteLine(answer);
   //debería devolver la información de la conexión

    sc = sshclient.CreateCommand("connect / as sysdba ");
    sc.Execute();
    answer = sc.Result;
    Console.WriteLine(answer);
    //debe devolver connected 

    sc = sshclient.CreateCommand("select * from v$LOG_HISTORY;");
    sc.Execute();
    answer = sc.Result;
    Console.WriteLine(answer);
      //el resultado de la consulta de la vista
```

no devuelve nada, esto me hace pensar que no se esta ejecutando,
que podría estar pasando o cual es el procedimiento correspondiente

Gracias

Comment: Hola! Que significa "no funciona"? Cuáles son los otros comandos que funcionan bien? (cuál es el código para esos comandos que te funcionan bien?) Por favor ve a [edit] y AÑADE eso a tu pregunta.

Comment: Hola Alfabravo
ya hice una edición espero ser mas claro en mi problema con este cambio, gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La diferencia en los comandos que estás ejecutando es que sqlplus es una sesión interactiva y el código que estás usando no parece lidiar bien con ese hecho.

Por qué no pruebas usar un usuario con permisos suficientes y correr el/los comandos SQL que necesites en una única instrucción? Algo como

`echo select * from v$LOG_HISTORY; | sqlplus user/password@database`

Comment: Si esta es la solución te agradezco mucho por tu tiempo funciono bien, gracias